# How can I prove Holder inequality for $0<p<1$?

Tags: analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $0<p<1$  snd $\dfrac{1}{p}+\dfrac{1}{p'}=1$. Notice that $p'<0$.
If $f \in L^{p}$ and $0<\int_{\Omega}\vert g(x) \vert^{p'}dx < \infty$ then, $$\int_{\Omega}\vert f(x)g(x) \vert dx \geq (\int_{\Omega}\vert f(x) \vert^{p}dx)^{\frac{1}{p}}(\int_{\Omega}\vert g(x) \vert^{p'}dx)^{\frac{1}{p'}} $$

The assumption on $g$ implies that $g>0$ almost surely.

Comment: A dotted capital I… Are you Turkish, by any chance?

Comment: Yes I am Turkish.

Comment: In case 0 < p < 1 the sum of inverses equal to 1 is impossible.

Comment: $p'=\frac{p}{p-1}<0$

Comment: Is this not false? Take the counting measure in $\mathbb{N}$, $f=\chi_{\{1\}}$ and $g=\chi_{\{2\}}$. Clearly $\int |fg|= 0$ and $\lVert g \rVert_p=\lVert g \rVert_{p'}=1$

Answer (score 5):

Write $h(x) = f(x)g(x)$. Without loss of generality (by multiplying $g$ and $h$ by constants) we can assume
$$ \left(\int |g|^{p'} dx \right)^{\frac{1}{p'}}= 1 = \int |h| dx $$
So what we want to prove reduces to
$$ \int |h / g|^p \leq 1 $$

To prove this, apply the regular Holder inequality: put $h^p$ in $L^{1/p}$ and $1/g^p$ in $L^{1/1-p}$. Observe that

$$ \frac{1}{|g|^{p/(1-p)}} = |g|^{p'}$$

Comment: In the first equation, on the left-hand side of the first equality, you must raise the integral to the power of $\frac{1}{p'}$